# how to secure this message functionality based on post and user id?

Tags: javascript, architecture

I'm totally into web dev, so I'm not sure if I should even name this issue "architectural". Lemme explain it

So I'm working on a car marketplace website where both buyers and sellers will come. users can create posts about their cars and anyone can send messages to that seller about any post he (seller) created. but I don't wanna make it like a social media where anyone can message anyone for no reason. so I wanted to create the message functionality based on two variables. one is the post id, and another is the user (message receiver) id. So if **User_1** wants to chat with **User_2**, they need to chat about some post that was created by either **User_1** or **User_2**. and besides that, if I use two variables in the message functionality, it would be easy for me to always show which post they're talking about at the top of their inbox.

At first, I thot to create the inbox link like the following: `/inbox/<POST_ID>/<MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>`. but in this case, we have a issue

Let's say we have three users

1. **User_1**
2. **User_2**
3. ***The_naughty_user***

Now let's say, **User_1** created a post with the post id of "**Post_id**". so to contact **User_1** about "**Post_id**", the inbox link would be: `/inbox/Post_id/User_1`

Now if ***The_naughty_user*** gets the id of **User_2**, he can do `/inbox/Post_id/User_2` and get into **User_2**'s inbox, which obviously we don't want.

We can check if `<MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID>` is the author of `<POST_ID>` and terminate the process if not. but in that case, the seller won't be able to send messages to the possible buyer (cuz the Possible Buyer is not the author of the post)

Now you can suggest not showing the IDs in the link and passing those in some other ways or encrypting them. but what I can think of is, showing or not showing the IDs isn't even the issue. even if we encrypt the IDs, and pass those in some other ways other than by the link, **The_naughty_user** just needs to swap the encrypted IDs

I don't know if I was clear enough. If yes, can u think of any possible solution to this problem? And if not, let me know what more info I can provide to help u understand the problem more

**Tech:** NextJS